# Monitor transactions of non-native asset

Tags: transactions, stellar-sdk, operations, horizon, new-developer

is there a convenient way to monitor all transactions/payments/operations of a custom asset? It seems like the REST API only allows this for either one account or the whole network, but not for a given asset_code/issuer combination.

I don't want to monitor offers or order books, but general activity.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [all effects endpoint](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/effects-all.html) in [streaming mode](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/responses.html#streaming), and programmatically filter trading and trustline [effects](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/effect.html) that involve the target asset.